# Best way to handle NullPointerException after Network Calls?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Most of the time, the network calls would finish AFTER the Fragment is detached, that's why the getActivity() returns null. What's your typical solution to this?

Solution #1: When the fragment goes paused, kill all the network calls.

Solution #2: Add a "isDetached()" checking

Solution #3: Add a "isAdded()" checking

Solution #4: Have a reference of the activity, mActivity

Comment: #4 is hardly a solution, it's just asking for problems. There is a reason getActivty() returns null

Comment: "What's your typical solution to this?" MVP. Read more about it [here](http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer solution 4. I had problems regarding accessing shared preferences and `getActivity()` was null. Having a reference to the activity solved this.

```
Activity mActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.mActivity = activity;
}
```